# Mobilevit Binary classification ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, image-classification

I am using the colab notebook(https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/mobilevit.ipynb) for **mobilevit** to train on a dataset I have of **25k pictures for 2 classes**. Since it's a **binary classification**, I have used **keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy** and **Sigmoid as activation function** at the last layer:-

```
def create_mobilevit(num_classes=2):
inputs = keras.Input((image_size, image_size, 3))
x = layers.Rescaling(scale=1.0 / 255)(inputs)

# Initial conv-stem -> MV2 block.
x = conv_block(x, filters=16)
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=16 * expansion_factor, output_channels=16
)

# Downsampling with MV2 block.
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=16 * expansion_factor, output_channels=24, strides=2
)
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=24 * expansion_factor, output_channels=24
)
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=24 * expansion_factor, output_channels=24
)

# First MV2 -> MobileViT block.
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=24 * expansion_factor, output_channels=48, strides=2
)
x = mobilevit_block(x, num_blocks=2, projection_dim=64)

# Second MV2 -> MobileViT block.
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=64 * expansion_factor, output_channels=64, strides=2
)
x = mobilevit_block(x, num_blocks=4, projection_dim=80)

# Third MV2 -> MobileViT block.
x = inverted_residual_block(
    x, expanded_channels=80 * expansion_factor, output_channels=80, strides=2
)
x = mobilevit_block(x, num_blocks=3, projection_dim=96)
x = conv_block(x, filters=320, kernel_size=1, strides=1)

# Classification head.
x = layers.GlobalAvgPool2D()(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="sigmoid")(x)

return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

And here's my dataset preparation cell:-

```
batch_size = 64
auto = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
resize_bigger = 512
num_classes = 2


def preprocess_dataset(is_training=True):
    def _pp(image, label):
        if is_training:
            # Resize to a bigger spatial resolution and take the random
            # crops.
            image = tf.image.resize(image, (resize_bigger, resize_bigger))
            image = tf.image.random_crop(image, (image_size, image_size, 3))
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
        else:
            image = tf.image.resize(image, (image_size, image_size))
        label = tf.one_hot(label, depth=num_classes)
        return image, label

    return _pp


def prepare_dataset(dataset, is_training=True):
    if is_training:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(batch_size * 10)
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_dataset(is_training), num_parallel_calls=auto)
    return dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(auto)
```

And this is the cell for training the model:-

```
learning_rate = 0.002
label_smoothing_factor = 0.1
epochs = 30

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
loss_fn = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(label_smoothing=label_smoothing_factor)


def run_experiment(epochs=epochs):
    mobilevit_xxs = create_mobilevit(num_classes=num_classes)
    mobilevit_xxs.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])

    checkpoint_filepath = "/tmp/checkpoint"
    checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        checkpoint_filepath,
        monitor="val_accuracy",
        save_best_only=True,
        save_weights_only=True,
    )

    mobilevit_xxs.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
    )
    mobilevit_xxs.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
    _, accuracy = mobilevit_xxs.evaluate(val_ds)
    print(f"Validation accuracy: {round(accuracy * 100, 2)}%")
    return mobilevit_xxs


mobilevit_xxs = run_experiment()
```

Basically the code is identical to https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/mobilevit.ipynb except for the change in BinaryCrossEntropy loss and Sigmoid as actv. func. I don't understand why I am getting this even though I am explicitly ont-hot-coded my class labels -

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `num_classes = 1` instead of num_classes = 2 as you have used [Sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid) activation function which returns the values between 0 to 1 for binary classification(0,1).

The values <0.5 will be considered as class 0 and values >0.5 will be as class 1 in between two binary classes (0,1).

Please refer to the replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/87ad4c8202295da2a2e04e6714adfeba/mobilevit-binary-classification-gist.ipynb) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificaton on this regard @TFer2. Going down the project pipeline I am encountering another issue, which I thought might be causing because of this one. But even after applying the BinaryCrossentropy for the loss function, I am getting wrong classification result at the Android appication side with the tflite version of the model. I have 2 classes as mentioned before and any input to the model is giving values around 0.79. Can you have a look into this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820285/image-processing-step-for-mobilevit-in-android-application

Comment: I am suspecting there is a specific way how the image should be parsed and fed to the model on the Android application. Right now I am just transforming images into Bitmaps and normalizing their pixel wise values from -1 to +1. Cannot find any Android implementation of Mobilevit anywhere so cannot verify