# Image processing step for Mobilevit in android application

Tags: android, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

My question is fairly simple and short. MobileViT is a mobile-friendly Transformer-based model for image classification and here is the link for it: https://keras.io/examples/vision/mobilevit/

I have used https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/mobilevit.ipynb to train on my dataset which has 2 classes. Everything's fine on the notebook side and I am getting ~78% accuracy on my test set. But I cannot find the android implementation with the tflite version of this model which is THE MAIN OBJECTIVE OF THIS ARCHITECTURE!

Maybe I am looking at the wrong resources or something else but I just cannot find any android implementation with Mobilevit anywhere. I tried on my own but the model is classifying all images with class 1 in my Android application, so I guess there is something different I have to do with my image processing step. Is there any link or source where the Android implementation of Mobilevit model is published, or just the image processing code snippet on Android?